# How can I save multiple basic shapes drawn on the same canvas with preview like in paint?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a app like paint where you can draw basic shapes with preview. I implemented a draw function for ellipse and next I want to implement one for a line and a rectangle. But I don't know how to store the already drawn shapes and restore them after. Also I don't know why I need two canvas elements if I want to draw with a preview. Thank you!

```
//JavaScript FILE
 let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let tempcanvas = document.getElementById("tempcanvas")
    
    var ctx = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
    var mainctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle="aqua";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    var widthCns = canvas.width, heightCns =  canvas.height, x1, y1;
    var isDown = false; 
    var savedDrawings = [];
    
    //Desenare cu un singur tip de instrument (elipsă)
    function drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2){
        var radiusX = (x2 - x1) * 0.5,   /// radius for x based on input
            radiusY = (y2 - y1) * 0.5,   /// radius for y based on input
            centerX = x1 + radiusX,      /// calc center
            centerY = y1 + radiusY,
            step = 0.01,                 /// resolution of ellipse
            a = step,                    /// counter
            pi2 = Math.PI * 2 - step;    /// end angle
        
        /// start a new path
        ctx.beginPath();
    
        /// set start point at angle 0
        ctx.moveTo(centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(0),
                   centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(0));
    
        /// create the ellipse    
        for(; a < pi2; a += step) {
            ctx.lineTo(centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(a),
                       centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(a));
        }
        
        /// close it and stroke it for demo
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    
    //Desenare cu un singur tip de instrument (dreptunghi)
    function drawRect(){
    
    }
    
    //Desenare cu un singur tip de instrument (linie)
    function drawLine(){
        
    }
    
    //Desenare cu mouse cu preview(elipsa, dreptunghi, line)
    //Implementat: elipsa
    
    /// handle mouse down    
    tempcanvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    
        // if(savedDrawings !== null)
        //     savedDrawings.pop();
        // while( ctx!== null){
        //     ctx.restore();
        // }
        ctx.restore();
        /// get corrected mouse position and store as first point
        var rect = tempcanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        x1 = e.clientX - rect.left;
        y1 = e.clientY - rect.top;
        isDown = true;
    }
    
    /// clear isDown flag to stop drawing
    tempcanvas.onmouseup = function() {
       // savedDrawings.push({X: x1, Y: y1});
       ctx.save();
        isDown = false;
    }
    
    /// draw ellipse from start point
    tempcanvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    
        if (!isDown) return;
        
        var rect = tempcanvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
            x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
            y2 = e.clientY - rect.top;
        
        /// clear temporal canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, widthCns, heightCns);
    
        /// draw ellipse
        drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

//HTML FILE
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" padding="15px" position="absolute" background-color="aqua" style="border: 1px solid black">
         </canvas>
        <!-- canvas temporal -->
        <canvas id="tempcanvas" width=800 height=500 padding="15px" position="absolute" background-color="aqua" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question: Why do you need two canvases for drawing with preview?**

**Answer:** One canvas is used to show preview while holding mouse button. When you move your mouse, whole canvas is redrawn. So it must be always cleared before drawing. If you comment line with *ctx.clearRect* you will see there are many shapes stacking for every move your mouse does.

Second canvas is used to store all drawn shapes. As you can see in bottom example, you can position temporary canvas with transparent background on top of main canvas, so it's look like you drawing in only one of them.

**Question: How to save already drawn shape to main canvas?**

**Answer:** Use *drawImage* method to copy image from temporary canvas to main canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const tempcanvas = document.getElementById("tempcanvas")

const ctx = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');
const mainctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
mainctx.fillStyle='#cec';
mainctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const widthCns = canvas.width, heightCns = canvas.height;
var isDown = false; 
var savedDrawings = [];

var x1, y1;

//Desenare cu un singur tip de instrument (elipsă)
function drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  let radiusX = (x2 - x1) * 0.5,   /// radius for x based on input
      radiusY = (y2 - y1) * 0.5,   /// radius for y based on input
      centerX = x1 + radiusX,      /// calc center
      centerY = y1 + radiusY,
      step = 0.01,                 /// resolution of ellipse
      a = step,                    /// counter
      pi2 = Math.PI * 2 - step;    /// end angle

  /// start a new path
  ctx.beginPath();

  /// set start point at angle 0
  ctx.moveTo(centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(0),
             centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(0));

  /// create the ellipse    
  for(; a < pi2; a += step) {
    ctx.lineTo(centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(a),
               centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(a));
  }

  /// close it and stroke it for demo
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.stroke();
}

/// handle mouse down    
tempcanvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  ctx.restore();
  
  /// get corrected mouse position and store as first point
  var rect = tempcanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  x1 = e.clientX - rect.left;
  y1 = e.clientY - rect.top;
  isDown = true;
}

/// clear isDown flag to stop drawing
tempcanvas.onmouseup = function() {  
  mainctx.drawImage(tempcanvas, 0, 0);
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, widthCns, heightCns);
  ctx.save();
  isDown = false;
}

/// draw ellipse from start point
tempcanvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;

  var rect = tempcanvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
      y2 = e.clientY - rect.top;

  /// clear temporal canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, widthCns, heightCns);

  /// draw ellipse
  drawEllipse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

```css
#canvas,
#tempcanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#tempcanvas {
  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="tempcanvas" width=800 height=500></canvas>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4v3r9pdt/3/

Nice article about canvas context *save* and *restore*: https://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/

Draw image documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: It worked! thank you! Is there another way to draw shapes with preview without using two canvas elements?

Comment: Also how can I make my buttons to select a shape when pressed and then to draw with that shape?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes there is a way to use only one canvas. But of course you must somewhere save result that you don't want to be redrawn(maybe image).
For any other unrelated problems please create another post.